# ANDROID - How to move to other fragment from fragment

Tags: android, fragment

Usually, if we want to go to other page. We use code

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

I confuse to go to other page with fragment.

*TEACHER_Class.java*

```
public class TEACHER_Class extends Fragment {

    Button tambahKelasButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.teacher_class, container, false); 
        tambahKelasButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tambah_kelas_button);
        tambahKelasButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment FRAGMENT = new TEACHER_AddClass();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                //I think I get error in here
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.layout.teacher_class, FRAGMENT);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

*TEACHER_AddClass.java*

```
public class TEACHER_AddClass extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.teacher_add_class, container, false); 

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

I want to move from **TEACHER_Class.java** to **TEACHER_AddClass.java**

This is teacher_class.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:background="#393f46"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
android:id="@+id/teacher_class_layout"
>

<!-- Login progress -->


<Button android:id="@+id/tambah_kelas_button"
        android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:text="TAMBAH KELAS" android:background="#f8255f"
        android:textSize="18sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/insert_class_form" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#999999"
        >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_column="3">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_class_name"
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="          NAMA KELAS"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7.5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7.5dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#f6f6f6"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_bank_soal"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="BANK SOAL"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#f6f6f6"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_resources"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="RES"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7.5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7.5dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="#f6f6f6"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

teacher_add_class.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" android:background="#393f46"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/teacher_add_class_layout"
>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ADD CLASS"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:id="@+id/loginTittle"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fullname_edittext"
                android:layout_width="330dp" android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" android:textColor="#282727"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:hint="Full Name"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/shortname_edittext"
                android:layout_width="330dp" android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" android:textColor="#282727"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:hint="Short Name"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/summary_edittext"
                android:layout_width="330dp" android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:textSize="18sp" android:textColor="#282727"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:hint="Summary"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add_class_button"
                android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp" android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                android:text="ADD" android:background="#f8255f"
                android:textSize="22sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />





</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: all fragment transactions should be done in the holding activity of the fragments

Comment: May be you are trying to replace a fragment that statically placed inside the xml file.

Comment: @tyczj is there a way for move to other fragment in fragment??

Comment: @Krish yes, you are true......

Comment: I have solution now. I have solution because layout which hold activity doesn't have fragment tag. It makes me feel confused. If it have fragment tag, I willn't confuse.

Answer (score 2):

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
```

you should use `getChildFragmentManager`, to perform transaction from a Fragment

```
   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.layout.teacher_class, FRAGMENT);
```

the first parameter has to be the id (`R.id.`) of the `ViewGroup` that hosts the Fragment itself, and not the id of layout.

Comment: My app use android SDK version below 17. So, I can't use getChildFragmentManager. How to replace getChildFragmentManager..

Comment: you can. It is also part of the support library

Comment: I have changed R.layout.teacher_class to id of linear layout from teacher class layout. Check out my updated question... But I still can't go to other page

Answer (score 0):

I suspect R.id.layout.teacher_class is the fragment you want removed?  The first argument for the replace function is the container holding the fragment, not the actual fragment to be replaced.

```
fragmentTransaction.replace([TARGET_CONTAINER], FRAGMENT);
```

Comment: I have filled TARGET_CONTAINER with id of linear layout from teacher_add_class.xml. But still get error, check out my updated question..

Comment: Where is the code and xml for the activity?  In the activity is where you should be doing your fragment transactions.